# Getting images from itunes rss feed and putting the pics in a bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, rss

So I am able to get the images of the albums from the itunes rss by using this code:

```
$("#parse").click(function (){
$(".bxslider").html("");
var country = $("#country").val();
var number = $("#top").val();
$.get("https://itunes.apple.com/"+country+"/rss/topsongs/limit="+number+"/xml" , function(data){
    var itunesArray = $(data).find("entry");
    itunesArray.each(function(){
        var image = $(this).find("im\\:image").eq(1).text();
        var audio = $(this).find("link").eq(1).attr("href");
```

HTML for my slider:

```
<div class="slider">
     <ul class = "bxslider">        
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I try to append the html by using this code:

```
$('.bxslider').append("<li><img src = "+image + " height = '100'  
width ='100' >" + "</li>");
```

Jquery for slider:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
             mode: 'fade',
             //captions: true,
             auto: true,
             //autoControls: true
             pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
             /*minSlides: 2,
             maxSlides: 2,
             slideWidth: 170,
             slideMargin: 10,
             ticker: true,
             speed: 7000*/
            });
```

I can get the images into the webpage but not inside the slider. I can see the arrows but I am unable to switch images and can see all of them at once. Im supposed to see them one at a time. I do not know whats going on. Any recommendations would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to initialize your `bxSlider` inside `$.get` Ajax success callback i.e. after all images has been added to DOM (exactly after `itunesArray.each()` loop).

I think you have not posted the entire code but you can just refer below code and take the idea (this code may not work directly as it is):

```
$("#parse").click(function (){
    $(".bxslider").html("");
    var country = $("#country").val();
    var number = $("#top").val();
    $.get("https://itunes.apple.com/"+country+"/rss/topsongs/limit="+number+"/xml" , function(data){
        var itunesArray = $(data).find("entry");
        itunesArray.each(function(){
            var image = $(this).find("im\\:image").eq(1).text();
            var audio = $(this).find("link").eq(1).attr("href");

            $('.bxslider').append("<li><img src = "+image + " height = '100' width ='100' >" + "</li>");

        });//each loop end

        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
             mode: 'fade',
             //captions: true,
             auto: true,
             //autoControls: true
             pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
             /*minSlides: 2,
             maxSlides: 2,
             slideWidth: 170,
             slideMargin: 10,
             ticker: true,
             speed: 7000*/
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: So I did this and it works, I am able to get the images inside the slider. Thanks. But now everytime I click the button I get another slider. So is it initializing a slider everytime I click the button? How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: Yes; everytime you click on parse button, the ajax call is going and slider is getting initialized with new set of images.  Could you please post your entire HTML showing this parse button and tell us what is the role of this button?

Comment: so I am getting user input about which country they want the feed to come from and the number of top songs they want to see from that country. I put these variable inside the itunes link for the ajax.

Comment: I added HTML for the Parse button. Thanks!

Comment: so, do you want like: if 'country' and 'number of songs' value  doesn't change (same as previous) and at that point if user press `parse` button then Do Not make ajax call as well as Do Not re-init slider?

Comment: Yes exactly and even if the user does change those values I want to make the ajax call but still not re-init the slider.